# How to replace small icons in SharePoint Online lists via JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting

For icons that display next to field names like so on lists:

[image]

How can we replace them with custom icons, or fluent UI icons?

My current JSON file for formatting the body, looks like this:

```json
{
    "sections": [
        {
            "displayname": "About the Recipe",
            "fields": [
                "Title",
                "Number of views",
                "Author",
                "Publishing Date",
                "Description",
                "Nutrition Facts",
                "Number of ingredients",
                "Number of servings",
                "Calories per serving"
            ]
        },
        ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not supported** using JSON Formatting yet.

> Unlike the header and the footer, body configuration **only allows defining one or more sections** and adding one or more columns into each of those sections.

**Source**: [Configure custom body with one or more sections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections)

Answer (score 1):

List form not support using JSON Formatting. So, you can not change small icon of list columns.

**You could refer to the following articles:**

- [Configure the list form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)
- [Finally, SharePoint Received Form Formatting](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/finally-sharepoint-received-form-formatting/)